# How do I get basic ProxyPass to work on Apache 2.2.17?

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to get around the ERR_UNSAFE_PORT restriction in Chrome by making Apache reverse proxy other HTTP servers on the machine.

1. I load mod_proxy with `sudo e2enmod proxy`
2. I add `ProxyPass /znc/ http://localhost:6667/` to my `httpd.conf`
3. I restart Apache with `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

When I open up `/znc/`, I get 500 Internal Server Error. I added `LogLevel debug`, restarted apache, tried again, and got nothing suspicous:

```
[Fri Oct 19 18:55:17 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1818): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 0 in child 21528 for worker http://localhost:6667/
[Fri Oct 19 18:55:17 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1934): proxy: initialized single connection worker 0 in child 21528 for (localhost)
[Fri Oct 19 18:55:17 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1818): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 1 in child 21528 for worker proxy:reverse
[Fri Oct 19 18:55:17 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1934): proxy: initialized single connection worker 1 in child 21528 for (*)
[Fri Oct 19 18:55:17 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.3.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Oct 19 18:55:17 2012] [info] Server built: Feb 14 2012 17:59:20
[Fri Oct 19 18:55:17 2012] [debug] prefork.c(1018): AcceptMutex: sysvsem (default: sysvsem)
[Fri Oct 19 18:55:22 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1818): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 0 in child 21532 for worker http://localhost:6667/
[Fri Oct 19 18:55:22 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1837): proxy: worker http://localhost:6667/ already initialized
[Fri Oct 19 18:55:22 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1934): proxy: initialized single connection worker 0 in child 21532 for (localhost)
[Fri Oct 19 18:55:22 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1818): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 1 in child 21532 for worker proxy:reverse
[Fri Oct 19 18:55:22 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1837): proxy: worker proxy:reverse already initialized
[Fri Oct 19 18:55:22 2012] [debug] proxy_util.c(1934): proxy: initialized single connection worker 1 in child 21532 for (*)
```

So I'm stumped at this point. What to do?

I'm running Ubuntu Server 11.10. ZNC responds with a correct 200 OK and HTML when queried directly both from the local machine and the Internet.

Answer (score 1):

One must also enable mod_proxy_http with `sudo a2enmod proxy_http`.